# loop through unique string in one column and create a dictionary or array of data from 2 other columns associated with the unique string

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-wrangling

I have many csv files with the same data structure as follows:

| y | x | variant_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 82 | 12 | F^W#Bfr18 |
| 76 | 3 | F^W#Bfr18 |
| 45 | 18 | *BCDS%q3rn |
| 59 | 14 | *BCDS%q3rn |
| ... | ... | ... |

I am trying to loop through each file and use the `groupby` function for the `variant_name` column and collect the corresponding data in the `x` and `y` columns and generate a scatter plot (axes are x and y, as the column names in this example).

`group = df.groupby('variant_name')`

I thought I could use a lambda function to hold all the x and y values that are associated with the specific `variant_name` but I'm completely stuck. I hope this makes sense. Please let me know if I need to clarify. Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking for a scatter plot per `variant_name`?  Otherwise I don't understand what you mean by columns in a scatterplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following code:

```py
df.groupby('variant_name').agg({'x': list, 'y':list})
```

you get:

```sh
                   x         y
variant                       
*BCDS%q3rn  [45, 59]  [18, 14]
F^W#Bfr18   [82, 76]   [12, 3]
```

Then you can iterate on the different variants and plot them:

```py
import pylab as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
for t in df.groupby('variant').agg({'x': list, 'y':list}).itertuples():
    ax.scatter(t.x, t.y, label=t.Index)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

**EDIT**

If you want a plot for each variant, you can move the creation of the figure in the body of the for:

```py
alpha = 1
for t in df.groupby('variant_name').agg({'x': list, 'y':list}).itertuples():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, num=t.Index)
    plt.suptitle(t.Index)
    ax.scatter(t.x, t.y, label=t.Index, alpha=alpha)
```

I added a parameter `alpha` here because, if you have a lot of points, it can improve your plot, helping in visualizing the density of your data.

On the other hand, if you're moving towards more complex plots, I suggest you to separate the plot code from the rest of your code:

```py
def _plot_variant(variant_data, alpha=1):
    fig_title = variant_data.variant_name
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, num=fig_title)
    plt.suptitle(fig_title)
    ax.scatter(variant_data.x, variant_data.y, alpha=alpha)

df.groupby('variant_name', as_index=False).agg({'x': list, 'y':list}).apply(_plot_variant, axis=1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you!! This worked amazingly. I have one issue which I didn't go into much detail with, but I have about 40 unique values in the "variant_name" column and thus would ideally make individual plots since the compiled version is really cluttered. Is there a way to loop through the unique string value and make one plot for each? Thank you again!!

Answer (score 2):

You can `.groupby` and get the mean and `plot` with `scatter`:

```
df = df.groupby('variant_name', as_index=False).mean()
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='x', y='y')
```

[image]

OR, you can pass a `hue` to a `sns.scatterplot` without `groupby`:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', hue='variant_name')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @David Erickson! This does work, and I am trying to loop through each unique name to generate plots for each (I have ~40 unique strings in that "variant_name" column!). Do you know how I can go about doing this? I am thinking I'd make a list of each unique string in that column, then loop through each one to plot the values that were saved from the previous snippet. Is that correct? If so, I might need more help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Seaborn is probably the way to go.  Pretty simple to split out the variants into their own chart.  `FacetGrid` has plenty of options to control the number of rows and columns etc.

```
import seaborn as sns
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='variant_name')
g.map_dataframe(sns.scatterplot, x='x', y='y')
```

[image]